# VPN to VPN gateway

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

So I have two computers. We'll call them Bob and Alice. Bob is a client on two VPN, one my own private, the other a publicly available one. Alice hosts a private VPN and a DHCP server. Now we have a third computer I want to connect to the VPN that we'll call Sally. Sally connects to Bob just fine, though once I'm on the VPN can't route the way I want.

I want to have Sally route their traffic through to Alice who will then route it to the public VPN. I can do this with out Bob hosting the private VPN.

Alice's VPN.conf

```
local 10.42.25.2

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/server.key  # This file should be kept secret

dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh2048.pem

server 10.42.26.0 255.255.255.0
route-gateway 10.42.26.1

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

verb 3

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Bob and Sally connect just fine to Alice's server using expected client configs.

Bob's iptables:

```
-A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

I can post more information as we go, but I'm not sure what else to post at this time.